# How use changefeed with 2 tables?

Tags: python, rethinkdb

I use rethinkdb changefeed and I need to catch event from one table with condition from another: first table contains some information, second table contains info about user and I need catch change in first table by the specific user. 
I tryed join tables and use changefeed with it, but it not works good.
Are there ways for it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to denormalize your data so that your changefeed only has to look at one table.